# how to count total record using Union All in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
select count(*) from ((select count(*) from employee )
 union ALL (select count(*) from events)) as total
```

this is my query i am trying to find ttoal record by given two query 
this query

```
 `select count(*) from employee`
```

give 300 record and

```
select count(*) from events
```

this give 100 when i try to count total record then it give always 2 record can any one tell me how to count total record by give query

Comment: You _don't_ need to use a `UNION` query here, just add together the individual table counts.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add together the two counts directly, no need for a `UNION` query:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM employee) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM events) AS total
```

Note that this will work because you used `UNION ALL`, which retains all the records in each side of the query.  If you wanted to use a `UNION` then it would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM employee
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM events
) t
```

But this would only work if the two tables have the same number (and ideally types) of columns.  I would probably go with the first option in any case.

Comment: If you equalize the columns like `select 'temp_val' temp_val` you won't face any issues

Comment: @webmaster I see no point in doing a `UNION` just to count, if the resulting combined tables are not used for anything else.

Comment: Hımm, are you pointing a performance issue here? Yeah that's right yours if faster thanks

Comment: Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
  this error is coming

Comment: @MakleeLee I warned of this in my answer, and this is why I recommended using subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    count(*) result.union_total 
from (
    (select 1 from table1) 
    union all 
    (select 1 from table2)
) result
```

Comment: still giving 2 record

Comment: I just tested it and gives me my tables correct amount

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Answer (score 0):

**Use this command:**

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM
  (SELECT * FROM db_domains where id=695
   UNION ALL
   SELECT * FROM db_domains where id=694
  ) AS A;
```

Result:  total: 2  ( According my sql table )

**Be sure that:**

1.The used SELECT statements have a same number of columns.

Otherwise you will get this error:
**Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns**

2.Every derived table must have its own alias. 
Otherwise you will get this error :
**Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias**

**See the snapshot in MYSQL Workbench. ( I have tested on workbench ):**

[image: Mysql Workbench]

[image]

In The last snapshot: You can see the result is: 1106

Comment: it always give 2  while it should give total 300+100 = 400

Comment: It gives the result according to condition is given in  "where" clause in the query.

Comment: @Maklee Lee Please see in the last snapshot, Its giving 1106 as result , because i removed the condition in where clause from the query.